# Spring data passing

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new with spring, and i'm following this creating project tutorial [tutorial link](https://fnoufal.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/creer-un-projet-spring-avec-eclipse/)

But my jsp don't know the data passed.

Here is my hello.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body> 
      votre message est : ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

and my helloController.java

```
package web;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class helloController {
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView helloWorld(){
  String message="Bonjour";
  return new ModelAndView("hello","message",message);
   }    
 }
```

and my web.xml

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>projetSpring</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="web"/>
    <bean id="viewResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix"><value>/jsp/</value></property>
          <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>      
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my project directory and the hello.jsp run result :

[Project directory + run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Kri.jpg)

Comment: try this : localhost:8080/projetSpring/hello.htm

Comment: Try to move the directory `jsp/hello.jsp` from `WebContent` to WEB-INF folder (WEB-INF\jsp\hello.jsp), and modify `name=prefix` property in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` for `/WEB-INF/jsp/`

Comment: Many thanks, it works with  localhost:8080/projetSpring/hello.htm , but please is it about url-pattern in the web.xml or it has no relation?

Comment: Yes right, "/jsp/hello.jsp" is not a valid expression for this pattern *.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are  accessing directly to your jsp page by using this url : [localhost:8080/projetSpring/jsp/hello.jsp](http://localhost:8080/projetSpring/jsp/hello.jsp)

You don't passe by your controller, you need to use the following url : [localhost:8080/projetSpring/hello.htm](http://localhost:8080/projetSpring/hello.htm) to invoke your DispatcherServlet and passe by your Controller

Comment: Improvement : try to move your JSPs inside WEB-INF to make them inaccessible for external use.